# Merge two lists without creating new nodes in C?

Tags: c, list

My exams are close and I'm stuck since the begin of the day on this problem:

> Write a function called AlternateLists () that takes as input two
>   lists and returns a third obtained alternating nodes of the two
>   inputs. Warning: the function must use the same nodes of input lists
>   and should not create new nodes.

The structure of the list is something like this:

```
struct nodo {
    int inf;
    struct nodo *succ;
    struct nodo *prec;
};
typedef struct nodo node;
```

Can somebody help me by giving an example of the function?

Here is my code, but it became a mess after all the day working on it.. Basicaly I've been trying to detach the node from list 2 and insert in list one. But I'm stuck in getting the over the first item in list two.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodo {
    int inf;
    struct nodo *succ;
    struct nodo *prec;
};
typedef struct nodo nodo;

nodo *RicercaPosizione( nodo *a, int i );
nodo *Inserisci(nodo *a, int i, int x);
nodo* AlternateLists(nodo* list1, nodo* list2);
void *MostraLista(nodo *a);

int main(){

    nodo *lista1=NULL;
    nodo *lista2=NULL;
    nodo *lista3=NULL;
    int numeri[]={1,2,3,4};
    int numeri2[]={5,6,7,8};

    int i=0; //filling the first list
    while(numeri[i]!='\0'){
        printf("%d",i);
        lista1=Inserisci(lista1,i, numeri[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("lista1 \n\n");
    MostraLista(lista1);
    lista2=lista1;
    printf("lista2 \n\n");
    MostraLista(lista2);
    printf("\n\nlista3 \n\n");
    lista3=AlternateLists(lista1,lista2);
    MostraLista(lista3);
}


nodo* AlternateLists(nodo* l1, nodo* l2){
    // Check if arrays are != NULL
    if(!l1 && !l2) return NULL;
    if(!l1) return l2;
    if(!l2) return l1;
    //----------------------
    nodo* c1 = l1;
    nodo* c2 = l2;
    nodo* next;
    nodo* next2;
    while(c1){
     next = c1->succ;
     if(c2){ // check to make sure there are still nodes in array2
       c1->succ = c2;
       next2 = c2->succ;
       c2->succ = next;
       c2 = next2;

     }else{
       c1->succ = next;
     }
     c1 = next;
    }
    /*while(c2){ //if there are more nodes in list 2 then there are in list 1
      c1->succ = c2;
      c2 = c2->succ;
    }*/
    return l1;
 }





//Insert etc.

nodo *Inserisci(nodo *a, int i, int x){
    nodo *q, *p;
    if ( i == 0 ){
        q = malloc(sizeof(nodo));
        q->succ = a; q->prec = NULL;
        q->inf = x;
        if (a != NULL)
            a->prec = q;
        a = q;
    } else {
        p = RicercaPosizione( a, i-1);
        if (p != NULL){
            q = malloc(sizeof(nodo));
            q->inf = x;
            q->succ = p->succ;
            q->prec = p;
            if ( p->succ != NULL)
                p->succ->prec = q;
            p->succ = q;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

nodo *RicercaPosizione( nodo *a, int i ){
    nodo *p = a;
    int j = 0;
    while ( j < i && p != NULL){
        p = p->succ;
        j = j+1;
    }
    return p;
}

void *MostraLista(nodo *a){
    nodo *p = a;

    while ( p != NULL ){
        printf("%d, ", p->inf);
        p = p->succ;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Have you given it an attempt? You don't even have the `AlternateLists` declaration.

Comment: (a) I'm tolerably certain the question has been asked and answered before on SO. (b) What have you tried?  What have you thought of trying?  It really isn't very hard.  (What's slightly more unusual is that you have a doubly-linked list; you'll need to take care of `prev` pointers as well as `next` pointers.)

Comment: Pop from each input list altenately and, if pop succeeds, push onto output list.  What's the problem, (apart from deciding what to do if the input lists are different lengths)?

Comment: Of course i've tried, i've spent all the day trying. I didn't paste what i've done because now it became a total mess.. Anyway i've been trying to detach the node from list 2 and insert in list one. But i'm stuck in getting the over the first item in list two. Now i'll update the question with my code..

My question was more on how would you have done it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - assuming that the list 'class' already has push/pop functions that take a list pointer as a parameter, this should be fairly easy?  If the lists don't have push/pop/insert/remove/whatever functions, they are not useable anyway.

Comment: Oh - spaghetti code:)

Comment: It is odd to be using all that counting with the list insertion code.  In your `AlternateList()` function, you have an unused variable `z` which is causing a memory leak since you `malloc()` a value for it to point at.  You also have an unused `z` in `UniSci()`.  The basic logic needs to be: _while (list1 not empty and list2 not empty) { add first item from list1 to output; add first item from list2 to output; } while (list1 not empty) { add first item from list1 to output; } while (list2 not empty) { add first item from list2 to output; } ._ Only one of the last two loops will execute.

Comment: You can also optimize the tail loops to a single splicing operation -- _if (list1 is not empty) add the rest of list1 to the output; if (list2 is not empty) add the rest of list2 to the output._

Comment: For this reason I was not pasting here the code, because while modifying it, it became a mess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node* AlternateLists(node* l1, node* l2){
 // Check if arrays are != NULL
  if(!l1 && !l2) return NULL;
  if(!l1) return l2;
  if(!l2) return l1; 
  //----------------------
  node* c1 = l1;
  node* c2 = l2;
  node* next;
  node* next2;
  while(c1){
   next = c1->next;
   if(c2){ // check to make sure there are still nodes in array2
     c1->next = c2;
     next2 = c2->next;
     c2->next = next;
     c2 = next2;
   }else{
    c1->next = next;
   }
   c1 = next;
 }
 while(c2){ //if there are more nodes in list 2 then there are in list 1
   c1->next = c2;
   c2 = c2->next;
   c1 = c2;
 }
 return l1;
```

}

The Idea here is a running pointer for both arrays `c1` and `c2` restructuring as you propagate through both of the lists.

Comment: All that conditional logic in the first loop is ungainly, isn't it?  See my later comments to the main question for how I think it should be done.

Comment: Why do you think i'm getting this error on line: 4? error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘node’ from type ‘struct node *’|

Comment: Sorry I wrote this in a hurry Im going to clean this up

Comment: Let me know if these changes help.

Comment: Really thanks for your help, you are awesome!

Anyway it works, but half.. Assuming that we have the lists: L1={1,2,3,4) and L2{1,2,3,4) the result should be: L3={1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4} but the actual result is: L3={1,1,3}.
I made small changes since my struct was in Italian and the second while is with wrong variables. I'll paste here my code:[link](http://pastebin.com/nabRZER7)

Comment: Please click the check mark under the up/down vote if it is the answer you are looking for :D

Comment: Sure ;) Are you so kind to have a quick check on my last comment? Thanks again!!

Comment: Wait I am a little confused as too what you are having trouble with? Everything works on my end

Comment: It works :) Just one problem about the c2 while.`/* At this point c1 is NULL */
while(c2){
   c1->succ = c2; /* Boom */
   c2 = c2->succ; 
   c1 = c2;
}`

Comment: Solved, just had to rewind c1 :)