# What does it means when I can't go inside a function? [C]

Tags: c, list

I'm trying to merge (alterning) two lists and create a third list without adding new nodes (question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328835/merge-two-lists-without-creating-new-nodes-in-c)). The code executes without errors or warnings but it seems to not entering into the function AlternateLists(), since is not printing the "Inside the function" string. What do you think it means? Can you give me a quick review and/or an expalanation to my code/problem?

Thanks..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodo {
    int inf;
    struct nodo *succ;
    struct nodo *prec;
};
typedef struct nodo nodo;

nodo *RicercaPosizione( nodo *a, int i );
nodo *Inserisci(nodo *a, int i, int x);
nodo* AlternateLists(nodo* list1, nodo* list2);
void *MostraLista(nodo *a);

int main(){

    nodo *lista1=NULL;
    nodo *lista2=NULL;
    nodo *lista3=NULL;
    int numeri[]={1,2,3,4};
    int numeri2[]={5,6,7,8};


    int i=0;
    while(i!=4){
        printf("%d",i);
        lista1=Inserisci(lista1,i, numeri[i]);
        i++;
    }


    printf("lista1 \n\n");
    MostraLista(lista1);
    lista2=lista1;
    printf("lista2 \n\n");
    MostraLista(lista2);
    printf("\n\nlista3 \n\n");
    lista3=AlternateLists(lista1,lista2);
    MostraLista(lista3);
}

nodo* AlternateLists(nodo* l1, nodo* l2){
printf("\n\n Inside the fuction");
 // Check if arrays are != NULL
  if(!l1 && !l2) return NULL;
  if(!l1) return l2;
  if(!l2) return l1;
  //----------------------
  nodo* c1 = l1;
  nodo* c2 = l2;
  nodo* next;
  nodo* next2;
  while(c1){
   next = c1->succ;
   if(c2){ // check to make sure there are still nodes in array2
     c1->succ = c2;
     next2 = c2->succ;
     c2->succ = next;
     c2 = next2;
   }else{
    c1->succ = next;
   }
   c1 = next;
 }
 while(c2){ //if there are more nodes in list 2 then there are in list 1
   c1->succ = c2;
   c2 = c2->succ;
   c1 = c2;
 }
 return l1;
 }

//Insert etc
nodo *Inserisci(nodo *a, int i, int x){
    nodo *q, *p;
    if ( i == 0 ){
        q = malloc(sizeof(nodo));
        q->succ = a; q->prec = NULL;
        q->inf = x;
        if (a != NULL)
            a->prec = q;
        a = q;
    } else {
        p = RicercaPosizione( a, i-1);
        if (p != NULL){
            q = malloc(sizeof(nodo));
            q->inf = x;
            q->succ = p->succ;
            q->prec = p;
            if ( p->succ != NULL)
                p->succ->prec = q;
            p->succ = q;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

nodo *RicercaPosizione( nodo *a, int i ){
    nodo *p = a;
    int j = 0;
    while ( j < i && p != NULL){
        p = p->succ;
        j = j+1;
    }
    return p;
}

void *MostraLista(nodo *a){
    nodo *p = a;

    while ( p != NULL ){
        printf("%d, ", p->inf);
        p = p->succ;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I ran the code and it segfaults before it calls the function 'AlternateLists'.

Comment: Make a debug build, run in a debugger and step through the code, line by line, to see what's happening.

Comment: Oh - it's 'spaghetti code' again:)   Debugger time.  @Lucas - if OP run had segfaulted, surely OP would have noticed and told us...

Comment: Hey!  OP!  Did it segfault or issue any other message?  If not, is it looping somewhere at 100% CPU?

Comment: I've never used the debugger, I'll try to study how it works..

Thanks..

@MartinJames Oh yes, again.. My near exam is about this :)

Comment: Oh dear:(  You MUST learn how to debug.  If you cannot debug, you cannot develop software - it's an essential skill.

Comment: @MartinJames What does OP stands for? Anyway I promise I will learn to debug!

Comment: 'Original Poster' - often saves writing 'he/she' :)

Comment: @mrxd , OP=Original Poster, the one who posted this question. It can also refer to Original Post.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, I found the problem and I made the answer to this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the problem :)

Thanks to everybody for the help!

The problem was when I was trying to copy the list in the main.

```
printf("lista1 \n\n");
MostraLista(lista1);
lista2=lista1;  \\This line was the problem..
printf("lista2 \n\n");
MostraLista(lista2);
printf("\n\nlista3 \n\n");
lista3=AlternateLists(lista1,lista2);
MostraLista(lista3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a debugger:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400810 in AlternateLists (l1=0x601010, l2=0x601010) at demo.c:67
67     c1->succ = c2;
```

The problem:

```
while(c1){
    ...
}
/* At this point c1 is NULL */
while(c2){
   c1->succ = c2; /* Boom */
   c2 = c2->succ; 
   c1 = c2;
}
```

Comment: The problem was about the two lists. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: But you are also right! Do you see any solution to this problem?

Comment: Rewind `c1` before `while(c2)`?

Comment: You are welcome ;), and spend some time learning how to use a debugger, is easy, really.

Answer (score 1):

Since you showed some interest in learning to debug, I'll try to answer your question.

If a function that should be entered unconditionally, such as 'AlternateLists' in your code, is not entered, there are some possible reasons:

1) The process crashed before it got to the call.  A segfault, or other serious error that comes to the attention of the OS, will terminate your process, usually with an error message of some sort.

2) The process/thread got blocked indefinitely before the call, or asked for such a long sleep that it was effectively blocked.  In that case, CPU use for that thread will be 0.

3) The process/thread got stuck in an infinite CPU loop before the call, or a loop so long that it seems infinite. In that case, CPU use for that thread will be 100%.